Newsletter plugin not working, not sent emails
I downloaded the strapi newsletter plugin and configured the website. It shows registered emails but does not send any emails, even if it shows that it has been sent. There is no error, but nothing arrives in the emails. What can I do or what feature can I try to use to send email? to let you know when there's a new post
